# Violación de segmento en código simple

Tags: c

Necesitaría saber si el siguiente código tiene algún tipo de violación de segmento, gracias.

```
char *create_memory(){
char *x = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);
strcpy(x, "WELL-DONE!");
return x;
```

Comment: Qué pasa cuando lo compilas? Y cuando lo ejecutas? Alguna violación de segmento?

Comment: El string ocupa 11 caracteres, tu reservas 12, asi que no deverias tener ningun problema. Cunado quieras hacer pruebas rapidas te recomiendo que aprendas a usar el address sanitizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He compilado tu código en un simple compilador online como puede ser programiz y tu código no tiene ningún error.
El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *create_memory()
{
    char *x = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);
    strcpy(x, "WELL-DONE!");
    return x;
}

int main() {

    char *x;

    x = create_memory();
    printf("%s", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Revisa bien tu modo de compilación, porque como te dicen en los comentarios no parece que haya un problema grave a priori en la reserva dinámica de memoria.

Comment: Lo interesante es que el OP nunca dice que le esté saliendo algún error.